# How to call function once in a static function in Swift?

Tags: swift

The code is like below,but I think we can't use dispatch_once token in Swift.

I tried use lazy and failed because lazy need to be used in a member class.

`'lazy' must not be used on an already-lazy global`

The class is static and have no variable to use,except for static variable.

```
@objc public class LaunchPipeLineApi : NSObject {
    
    private static var shared = Applaunch_AppLaunchMetrics()
    
    @objc public static func markApplicationStartTime() {
        shared.applicationStartTime = Int64(1000*Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970);
    }

    @objc public static func markApplicationEndTime() {
        shared.applicationEndTime = Int64(1000*Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970);
    }

    @objc public static func markFirstFrameRenderEndTime() {
        shared.firstFrameRenderEndTime =  Int64(1000*Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970);
    }

    @objc public static func markFirstInteractiveTime() {
        shared.firstInteractiveTime =  Int64(1000*Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970);
    }
        
    @objc public static func startReportAppLaunchMetrics(report:(_:String,_:Data) ->()) {
//here,I want to call this report only once even the function caller do multiple calls.How can I do?
        do {
            report("AppLaunchMonitor",try shared.serializedData())
        } catch {}
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You cannot use lazy on static variables or global because they are always lazy. Thats what the error says.

Comment: @Sulthan I am new to swift, I just add the complete code

Comment: @Rob I just update the complete code

Comment: I call startAndReportAppLaunchMetrics in different place,and It might be not thread-safe,so I want it call only once.In Objc,I can use a static variable dispatch_once token,but I can't do it in swift.

Comment: @Rob,I can't move to Applaunch_AppLaunchMetrics,it's protobuffer-generated class

Comment: Unrelated, but if `LaunchPipeLineApi` has a property called `shared`, as a matter of convention, one would assume that in the absence of any qualifier, that `shared` would be an instance of `LaunchPipeLineApi`, not of `Applaunch_AppLaunchMetrics`. Whenever you see a `static` property of `shared`, by itself, it is invariably an instance of that class, not of some other class. If you really meant it to be some other type, I might call it `sharedMetrics` or move this into  `Applaunch_AppLaunchMetrics `, to resolve this ambiguity. (Also, I'd replace those `Date.init()` references with `Date()`.)

Answer (score 1):

The most common use of `dispatch_once` was the thread-safe instantiation of some shared instance. E.g. consider:

```
@implementation MyObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MyObject *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

In Swift, we now achieve the exact same behavior much more simply:

```
class MyObject {
    static let shared = MyObject()
}
```

That offers the same thread-safe instantiation logic as that Objective-C pattern.

---

In your example, you have the `static` property, `shared`, which already enjoys this thread-safe, run-only-once, pattern. (I would make it a `let` rather than a `var`, though.)

So, you have your thread-safe instantiation logic already. So the question is whether you really need this `dispatch_once` sort of behavior for the `report` of the `serializedData`. Can you just put that in the `init` method of the `Applaunch_AppLaunchMetrics` class? That would be easiest, cutting the Gordian knot.

If you *really* want `dispatch_once` sort of logic for `startReportAppLaunchMetrics` (even though the `static` property `shared` already has that behavior), you can just have some state property to keep track of this (and then synchronize it with a lock or GCD serial queue or whatever). For example:

```
static let lock = NSLock()
static var hasRun = false

static func thisCanBeCalledMultipleTimesFromMultipleThreadsButRunOnlyOnce() {
    lock.lock()
    defer { lock.unlock() }

    if !hasRun {
        hasRun = true

        // do something
    }
}
```

Or

```
static let synchronizationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "synchronizationQueue")
static var hasRun = false

static func thisCanBeCalledMultipleTimesFromMultipleThreadsButRunOnlyOnce() {
    synchronizationQueue.async {
        if !hasRun {
            hasRun = true

            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can do that if absolutely needed, but I cannot help but wonder that, given that your `shared` already enjoys thread-safe, dispatch-once, sort of behavior that all `static` properties enjoy, do you really need that in this `report` of the `serializedData`, too?

Comment: OK. But a caller might be exceeding confused if they called `startReportAppLaunchMetrics` and it didn't call the `report` closure at all. This would be exceedingly hard to reason about at the calling point. I might change it to call the closure to be a `(String?, Data?, Error?) -> Void` closure or a `(Result<(String, Data), Error>) -> Void`, and make sure to call it with either the `String/Data` or `Error` regardless. Or have it `throw` errors and just return the `(String, Data)` (as it is a little strange to have a non-escaping closure at all in this context).

Comment: But having closure (non-escaping one, too) that are sometimes called and sometimes not called is likely to be a source of confusion. When we supply a closure, you expect it to be called.

Comment: I agree with @Rob that this behavior is confusing. @HensonFang If you go with this approach, perhaps the func could return a success/fail bool, or `throw` an error if `hasRun` was already true.  Then callers will have some small chance to know that the closure was not run when they called this method.  Still a code smell IMO, but some info giving insight into behavior could be better than no info.

Comment: I put a breakpoint at this function and it crashed once,so I came to think is this function not thread-safe,so I am going to make it thread-safe,as I do in ObjC with a dispatch once.In addition,the closure should be called only once at an application lifetime.Anyway,thanks for your advice,I will think it again.